# Difference between com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers and com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, foundation, entitlements

Does anyone know the difference between these 2 entitlement keys?

(I've corrected the second identifier from my last question which was incorrectly asked - I didn't mean the kvstore container but the ubiquity container).

Apple's documentation in different places says both are for the same thing: enabling iCloud document storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers` is related to [CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/cloudkit/), not to iCloud documents. This key is [badly documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_icloud-container-identifiers), but it is added to your Entitlements file when you select a CloudKit container in the iCloud section of the Target settings of your app in Xcode.

iCloud document storage is a little bit older, maybe because of that [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingiCloud.html) for `com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers` is much clearer.

Comment: Thanks @Ely, that makes sense. Is this something you learned from experience, or is it documented anywhere?

Comment: @GauravSharma I have extended my answer a bit.